# LaTeX output garbled when using Powerdot

Tags: powerdot

I'm using TexLive 2017, and I'm trying to make a slideshow using powerdot. Here is my "Minimum **not**-Working Example":

```
% !TeX program = latex
\documentclass{powerdot}
\title{My Slideshow}
\author{Dolf}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{slide}{Slide 1}
        Hi there.
    \end{slide} 
\end{document}
```

Output of `latex doc.tex`:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./doc.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/powerdot/powerdot.cls
Document Class: powerdot 2015/11/29 v1.5a powerdot presentation class (HA)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver: hdvips.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
))
`PSTricks' v2.74  <2017/06/15> (tvz)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.con))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-ovl/pst-ovl.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-ovl/pst-ovl.tex
`pst-ovl' v0.07, 2016/05/03 (tvz,hv)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/powerdot/powerdot-default.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/pifont.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upzd.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upsy.fd))
<powerdot-default.ps>)) (./doc.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./doc.bm) (./doc.bm) (./doc.toc) [1] [2] (./doc.aux) )
Output written on doc.dvi (2 pages, 7244 bytes).
Transcript written on doc.log.
```

Screenshot of `xdvi doc.dvi`:

[image: Screenshot of xdvi trying to render doc.dvi]

Screenshot of `xreader doc.dvi`:

[image]

I'm not sure if the problem is with the reader, the powerdot package, or the compilation. Any help is appreciated.

**Update (2018-03-05):**

I tried using `dvipdf` and `dvips` → `ps2pdf`, too! In both cases, the PDF looks like this, both with `acroread` and with `xreader`:

[image]

If I open `doc.ps` with `xreader`, it looks like this, which is more promising, but still wrong:

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your issues, it looks good with `latex`->`dvipdf` on my machine.

Comment: I think you need to generate postscript/pdf from the dvi, I'm not sure all the specials powerdot uses are supported by xdvi

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because powerdot relies on Postscript and has to be processed with a Postscript interpreter before viewing.

Comment: I voted for reopening, but with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` I get the expected result.

Comment: `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` gives the expected output on my machine too. Maybe this might help [texlive 2017 broke powerdot](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/rd4h5q1e-eM)? (*"You need to call dvips with the `-L0` switch."*)